# Editable, Typable but not removal in pretyped text - Text Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textfield

I want to put some text and display it in a text field. I want the user not to be able to remove this text but only can add some more text to it. Can I do this?

I want to display "http://" prefix in the textfield and the user should be only able to add some more text to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not possible. I would recomment doing one of the following:

- Write the http:// in front of the Textfield

> ```
> http:// [Textfield]
> ```

- do some form-validation: does the input submited contain http:// (at the beginning) ? if not add it

Comment: Yeap, that's what I did. Thanks.